# tkinter cannot locate image in PyCharm

Tags: python, image, tkinter, pycharm

The code below is what I have attempted. I have attempted using other codes but the results are all the same with the image not showing.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Using Icons, Images, and Exit Buttons')
root.iconbitmap('c:\Python images\die1.ico')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Micro$oft windoZe insists on using `\` for paths, you need r"c:\Python images\die1.ico" to escape the backslashes, or two \.  Otherwise ":" is meant, which is a very different char.

However better is to use `pathlib.Path` to handle all this for you, or the older `os.path` libraries.